# Recovering 4-vector Lorentz transformation from spinor formalism

Tags: special-relativity, relativity, tensor-calculus, spinors

I'm trying to recover the 4-vector transformation laws using spinors. I have defined

$$v^{\dot{a}b} = v^{\nu} \sigma_{\nu}^{\dot{a}b}$$

as usual, with $\sigma_0=1$.

Now with the rules for dotted and undotted spinor indices i get the transformed v for a boost in the z-direction

$$v^{\dot{a}b} \rightarrow v^{\dot{a'}b'}= \left({\mathrm{e }}^{ -   \theta \frac{\sigma_3}{2}} \right)^{\dot{a'}}_{\dot{a}} \left({\mathrm{e }}^{ \theta \frac{\sigma_3}{2}} \right)^{b'}_{b} v^{\dot{a}b}  = \begin{pmatrix}
   {\mathrm{e }}^{-  \frac{\theta}{2}}&0 \\ 0&{\mathrm{e }}^{  \frac{\theta}{2}} 
\end{pmatrix}   
\begin{pmatrix}
 v_0+v_3&v_1-iv_2\\v_1+iv_2&v_0-v_3
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
   {\mathrm{e }}^{ \frac{\theta}{2}}&0 \\ 0&{\mathrm{e }}^{ - \frac{\theta}{2}} 
\end{pmatrix}$$

where i have used the fact that $\sigma_3$ is diagonal and that ${\mathrm{e }}^A= \begin{pmatrix}
  {\mathrm{e }}^{A_{11}}&0\\0&{\mathrm{e }}^{A_{22}}
\end{pmatrix}$ holds for every diagonal matrix A. This gives me the wrong transformation!

It would give me the correct transformation if I had

$$v^{\dot{a}b} \rightarrow v^{\dot{a'}b'}= \left({\mathrm{e }}^{ -   \theta \frac{\sigma_3}{2}} \right)^{\dot{a'}}_{\dot{a}} \left({\mathrm{e }}^{ \theta \frac{\sigma_3}{2}} \right)^{b'}_{b} v^{\dot{a}b}  = \begin{pmatrix}
   {\mathrm{e }}^{-  \frac{\theta}{2}}&0 \\ 0&{\mathrm{e }}^{  \frac{\theta}{2}} 
\end{pmatrix}   
\begin{pmatrix}
 v_0+v_3&v_1-iv_2\\v_1+iv_2&v_0-v_3
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
   {\mathrm{e }}^{ - \frac{\theta}{2}}&0 \\ 0&{\mathrm{e }}^{ \frac{\theta}{2}} 
\end{pmatrix}$$

But I can't figure out why this should be the case. The only possibility I can think about would be if a relation like 
$\ A'_{\nu\mu} =  M_{\mu}^{\ \rho}(M_{\nu}^{\ \theta})^{-1}A_{\rho\theta }$ $\rightarrow$ $A'=MAM  $ would hold, but i can't find a formula like this. Doing the summation by hand i get the same result as with normal matrix multiplication without using the inverse matrix on the right hand side. Any tip or help would be much much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are four complex 2-dimensional spaces of "spinors with two components":

$V$ space of **right spinors**, with the **abstract index notation**: $\xi^a$,

$\overline{V}$ space of  **conjugate spinors**, $η^{\dot{a}}$, (the complex linear space of linear maps $\overline{V}^*\to C$)

$V^∗$ space of **dual spinors**, $\xi_a$, (the complex linear space of linear maps $V\to C$)

$\overline{V}^∗$ space of **dual-conjugate spinors** or **left spinors**, $\eta_{\dot{a}}$ (the complex linear space of *anti-linear* maps $V\to C$)

There is a non-degenerate skew-symmetric form $\epsilon: V\otimes V \to C$ and 
it fixes **canonical bases** in $V$: all those where $\epsilon$ is represented by the matrix $i\sigma_2$.

If $\{e_i\}_{i=1,2}$ is such a canonical basis, every other canonical basis is obtained as $\{e'_i\}_{i=1,2}$, with:

$$e_i = {L^j}_i e'_j \quad L \in SL(2,C)\:,$$

so that

$\xi = \xi^a e_a = \xi'^b e'_b$ verifies:

$$\xi'^b = {L^b}_a \xi^a\:.$$

A canonical basis $\{e_a\}_{a=1,2}\subset V$ induces analogous **associated canonical bases** in $V^*$, $\overline{V}$ and $\overline{V}^*$, respectively indicated by $\{e^{*a}\}_{a=1,2}\subset V^*$, $\{\overline{e}_{\dot{a}}\}_{a=1,2}\subset \overline{V}$, $\{\overline{e}^{\dot{a}}\}_{a=1,2}\subset \overline{V}^*$, by the requirments:
$$e^{*a}(e_b)= \delta^a_b\:, \quad  \overline{e}_{\dot{a}}(\overline{e}^{*\dot{b}}) = \delta^{\dot{b}}_{\dot{a}}\:,\quad \overline{e}^{*\dot{a}}(e_b) = \delta^{\dot{a}}_b$$

Referring to these bases, if $\xi^a \in V$ then $\overline{\xi^a} \in \overline{V}$, therefore components of tensors in $\overline{V}$ transforms with $\overline{L}$, when changing canonical basis. Similarly in $V^*$ one has to use $L^{t-1}$ and $L^{\dagger -1}$ in $\overline{V}^*$.

Finally, with the given definitions, there is a canonical isomorphism iduced by the metrical spinor $V \to V^*$, in components of canonical bases (there is a sign to be fixed depending on preferred conventions)

$$\xi^a \to \eta_{b}:= i \sigma_{2 ab} \xi^a\:.$$

The relation between spinors and $4$-vectors is based on the following theorem connecting real 4-vectors with Hermitean tensors in $V\otimes \overline{V}$.

**THEOREM.** *Let $\pi: SL(2,C) \to SO(1,3)\uparrow$ be the covering Lie-group homomorphism ($SL(2,C)$ being the universal covering of $SO(1,3)\uparrow$). Let $\{e_a\}_{a=1,2}$ and $\{\overline{e}_{\dot{a}}\}_{a=1,2}$ be associated canonical bases of $V$ and $\overline{V}$ respectively and $\{f_\mu\}_{\mu=0,1,2,3}$ a pseudo-orthonormal basis in Minkowski spacetime.
If $v:= v^\mu f_\mu$ is a real $4$-vector  and $\Xi_v := v^\mu \sigma_\mu^{a\dot{b}} e_a\otimes \overline{e}_{\dot{b}}$, then:*

$$\Xi_{\pi(L)v} = L \Xi_v L^{\dagger}\:, \quad \forall L \in SL(2,C)\:.$$

If $L$ is such that $\pi(L)$ is a boost, then, as is well-known $L=L^\dagger$, so your final supposition is true.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how certain are you that the ($i\sigma_2$) invariant matrix lives in $V^* \otimes V^*$?

Comment: I am not sure to understand well your question. We are referring to a linear map from $V\otimes V$ to $\mathbb{C}$ (equivalently, bilinear from $V\times V$ to $\mathbb{C}$), so this map stays in the dual space of the above tensor product. That dual space is $V^*\otimes V^*$.

Comment: Yes sorry it wasnt clear. Mostly was unsure if the bilinear form took two undotted spinors or one of each type. But after some reflecting it's clear. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First thing is that you are missing the imaginary unit in the exponential. The correct transformation matrix should be
$$M=e^{i\frac{\theta}{2}}.$$
Up to this small misprint, the first expression you wrote actually gives the desired transformation of the components $v_1$ and $v_2$. If we do the computation
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\begin{pmatrix}
   {\mathrm{e }}^{-  \frac{i\theta}{2}}&0 \\ 0&{\mathrm{e }}^{  \frac{i\theta}{2}} 
\end{pmatrix}   
\begin{pmatrix}
 v_0+v_3&v_1-iv_2\\v_1+iv_2&v_0-v_3
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
   {\mathrm{e }}^{ \frac{i\theta}{2}}&0 \\ 0&{\mathrm{e }}^{ - \frac{i\theta}{2}} 
\end{pmatrix}=\\
&\begin{pmatrix}
v_0+v_3 & e^{-i\theta }(v_1-iv_2) \\
e^{i\theta }(v_1+i v_2) & v_0 + v_3
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{aligned}
$$
This implies
$$
\begin{aligned}
v_1'-iv_2'&=e^{-i\theta}(v_1-iv_2),\\
v_1'+iv_2'&=e^{+i\theta}(v_1+iv_2),
\end{aligned}
$$
that finally gives the correct transformation.

I'm not sure, may be you made a mistake in multiplying of matrices.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. What you consider is a rotation, i'm looking at a boost, therefore there is no "i" in the exponent. Furthermore this is exactly my problem: I get a rotation as a result if i take a look at a boost and a boost if i'm considering a rotation. Dotted and undotted indices transform the same under rotations but differ under boost by a minus sign. This gives rise to the problem described above. For a boost i need the same exponents on both sides, for a rotation i need different signs in the exponent.

Comment: I derived the transformation laws for dotted and undotted indices and checked them with a book: $ v^{\dot{a'}b}= \left({\mathrm{e }}^{ \vec{ i \phi} \vec{\frac{\sigma}{2}} -  \vec{ \theta} \vec{\frac{\sigma}{2}}} \right)^{\dot{a'}}_{\dot{a}}  v^{\dot{a}b}   $ and 
$ v^{\dot{a}b'}= \left({\mathrm{e }}^{ \vec{ i \phi} \vec{\frac{\sigma}{2}} +  \vec{ \theta} \vec{\frac{\sigma}{2}}} \right)^{b'}_{b}  v^{\dot{a}b}   $ But if there is anything wrong with them, this would explain a lot.

Comment: @JakobH It seem to me that there is nothing wrong in your final suggestion, whereas I do not understand what is the general rule you assume to transform spinors.  Since I adopt different conventions I have to ask you to make explicit yours. Referring to yours what is the transformation rule for dotted spinors? I mean, if $\xi'^a = {L^a}_b \xi^b$ then $\eta^{\dot{a}} = {M^{\dot a}}_b \eta^{\dot{b}}$. What is the relation between $L$ and $M$ referring to your conventions?

Comment: I can transform a dotted (LH) into a undotted (RH) spinor by complex conjugating and multiplication with $i \sigma^2$. To be explicit $i \sigma^2 (\Psi_L)^{\star} = \Psi_R$ . I don't know any rule relating the transformation laws L and M as you indicated explicitly because i have never done it, but a first guess would be that $i \sigma^2$ does this. Do i have to transform the indices of the transformation acting on the undotted indice first to dotted before i can write it in matrix form? If yes, why?

Comment: I would suspect this closely related to $\ A'_{\nu\mu} =  M_{\mu}^{\ \rho}M_{\nu}^{\ \theta}A_{\rho\theta }$ $\rightarrow$ $A'=MAM^T$, where the matrix on the RHS has to be transposed before it is written in matrix form on the RHS, but i can't figure out the explicit law for the spinor indices

Comment: It seems to me that you are making confusion between $\eta^{\dot{a}}$ and $\eta_{\dot{a}}:= i{\sigma_2}_{ab} \eta^{\dot{b}}$. What you need for passing to vector from spinors are double spinors $\Xi^{a\dot{b}}$ and not ${\Xi^a}_{\dot{b}}$

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. Unfortunately i still can't make it work. I'll try to formulate my problem in your symbols:I have a double spinor $\Xi^{a\dot{b}}$  and i want to transform it. I'm going to use the transformation matrix R for RH spinors and L for LH spinors.  Therefore $(\Xi')_{a'\dot{b'}}= R_{a' a} L_{\dot{b'} \dot{b}} (\Xi)^{a\dot{b}} = R_{a' a}  (\Xi)^{a\dot{b}} L_{ \dot{b'} \dot{b}} \rightarrow R \Xi L^T$ where in the last line i moved to matrix notation. This gives me the wrong result because for a boost along the z-axis $L^T=L$ and R and L differ by a sign in the exponent.

Comment: Ok right spinors are those of the form $\xi^{a}$, left spinors are those with the form $\eta_{\dot{a}}$. When those of the first class transform with $M\in SL(2,C)$, those of the second class transform with ${M^\dagger}^{-1}$. There are however spinors of tipe $\eta^{\dot{a}}$. They transforms with $\overline{M}$. They are obtained from left spinors by applying $i\sigma_2$.  **4-vectors** are obtained using the **first** and the **third** type: $(\Xi_v)^{a\dot{b}} = v^\mu \sigma_\mu^{a\dot{b}}$.

Comment: Therefore transforming $v$ with $\Lambda$ is equivalent to transform $\Xi_v$ as $M^a_c\overline{M}^b_d \Xi^{a\dot{b}}$, namely: $\Xi \to M \Xi M^\dagger$. Boosts fulfil $M=M^\dagger$.

Comment: Ok, that was my mistake, I missed the fact that you are considering boosts. Then I would think that one should distinguish between $\sigma_\mu{}^{a\dot{a}}$ and $\sigma_{\mu}{}^{a}{}_{\dot{a}}$. If you raise and lower indices by $\epsilon_{ab}$, as I do, then the vector $v^{a\dot{a}}$ has the form different from what you wrote in your question. According to my calculations, this gives the correct answer.

Comment: @V.Moretti I think this would explain everything. What does the bar denote in your notation? I'm trying to figure out the transformation properties for the third type, but i always end up at the same transformation property (at least for boost) like for the second type.

Comment: @Edvard Yes i do raise and lower indices by $\epsilon_{ab}$ like you do. What does your $v^{a \dot{a}}$ look like?

Comment: the bar is the complex conjugation. You have 4 spaces: $V$ spinors $\xi^a$, $\overline{V}$ conjugate spinors $\eta^{\dot{a}}$, $V^*$ dual spinors $\xi_{a}$, $\overline{V}^*$ dual conjugated spinors $\eta_{\dot{a}}$. When you change spinors in $V$ with some $L \in SL(2,C)$, spinors in the other spaces change under the action of, respectively: $\overline{L}$, $L^{t-1}$, $\overline{L^{t-1}}=L^{\dagger-1}$.

Comment: Moreover, if $\xi \in V$ then $\overline{\xi} \in \overline{V}$, whereas you pass from $V$ to $V$ by lowering the index using the metric spinor $\epsilon$ that assumes the form $i\sigma_2$ in "canonical bases". Combining $\epsilon$ and $\overline{\cdot}$ you pass from $V$ to $\overline{V}^*$. The relation with $4$-vectors is written as above using tensors of $V\otimes \overline{V}$.

Comment: Yes! Thats it! It works. Thank you guys so much! The last thing i would have thought about is that my matrix form for $v^{a \dot{b}}$ is wrong. My definitions were inconsistent and thats why i ended up with the wrong result. If i start with $v_b^{\dot{a}}=v^{\mu} \sigma_{\mu}{}^{a}{}_{\dot{a}} $ with the usual pauli matrics and the then to get to my 4-vector as V.Moretti indicated as $v^{c \dot{a}}$ instead of $v_c^{ \dot{a}}$ i had before $\epsilon^{cb} v_b^{\dot{a}} = v^{c \dot{a}} = \begin{pmatrix}
  v_1+iv_2&-(v_0+v_3) \\v_0-v_3&-(v_1-iv_2)
\end{pmatrix}$ and everything works out correctly

Comment: @JakobH I added an overall answer. Bye, Valter